# How can I use ERB from a generated scaffold to my main page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, models, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a main page that is currently static and I also have a group of pages that I generated from a scaffold.

I would like to add the embedded ruby objects from the scaffold to the main page. I'm not sure if I have to do something with the controller, models, or the routes.

For example: <% @projects.title %> on my main page. As of now I receive the NoMethodError Undefined Method. Which I get, but I'm stuck as to how to troubleshoot.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Your main page has a controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have either ways...

1st is to load instance variable through your static pages controller

**..app/controllers/staticPages.rb**

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  ...      
  def mainPage
    @projects = Project.all
  end
  ...
end
```

Then you iterate over this collection in your view using something like the following

**..app/views/static_pages/main.html.erb**

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <div>
    ...
    <p><%= project.name %></p>
    <p><%= project.other_stuff %></p>
    ...
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Or you can just load the collection from your view

**..app/views/static_pages/main.html.erb**

```
<% Project.all.each do |project| %>
  <div>
    ...
    <p><%= project.name %></p>
    <p><%= project.other_stuff %></p>
    ...
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `<% Project.all.each do |project| %>` this is a bad idea to put `query` in your view file.

And with your `controller name` as `mainPage`, you must put `mainpage.html.erb` as your view file.